# Alexa getting response from user after prompt

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

So we are setting up a system in which a user can set reminders. Currently my intent is set up to provide a `Day` and a `Time`. If I say something like `set reminder for next tuesday at 9pm`, in my intent I see the values coming in fine. The issue is if let's say they say something like `set reminder for next tuesday`, they gave us the day but not time. So in my intent, I have this response:

```
      else if(obj.Day.value && !obj.Time.value) {
        this.response.speak(`Looks like you requested a reminder on ${obj.Day.value}, what time would you like the reminder set for?`).listen('Thanks');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.response, null, 2));
        this.emit(':responseReady');
      }
```

The issue I am having is... how do I get what they said? I've also tried `this.emit(':ask', '...')` but I still don't see what they actually say.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, essentially this is a simplified question.

How do we get the response from the user (for missing information) after Alexa asks something in an intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you will want to use the `elicitSlot` Directive. [Docs found here.](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#elicitslot)

Try:

```
    this.emit(':elicitSlot','slotName','intentName');
```

Alexa will know that you want to fill the next user's response to the `Time` slot, if you put `"Time"` into the `slotName` property above.

In the Alexa Console, you can specify how Alexa should elicit that slot. You can even provide multiple ways of asking and Alexa will choose one.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely try this.